# Unit ball of Bounded Operators is SOT - Complete

Tags: functional-analysis

I want to prove that $B=\{x\in \mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H}):||x||\leq 1\}$ (where $\mathcal{H}$ is a Hilbert space) is closed in the strong operator topology. My attempt is as follows,

Let $(x_n)_n$ be a SOT-Cauchy sequence in $B$. The limit exists since $\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})$ is Banach.

I know that the SOT-limit means $x_n\rightarrow x \iff \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }||x_n\zeta-x\zeta||=0\quad \forall \zeta\in \mathcal{H}$ but I'm not sure how to prove that $||x||\leq 1$ from this definition. Any hints would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Recall the definition of the norm on $\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $\{x_n\}$ is a sequence in $B$ that is $\text{SOT}$-convergent to $x\in\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})$.  I will show that $x\in B$.
Fix $\zeta\in\mathcal{H}$ with $\|\zeta\|\leq1$ and $\varepsilon>0$.  Then there is some $N\in\mathbb{N}$ with $\|x\zeta-x_n\zeta\|<\varepsilon$ for $n\geq N$, and thus
$$\|x\zeta\|\leq\|x_n\zeta\|+\|x\zeta-x_n\zeta\|<1+\varepsilon. $$
Since $\varepsilon>0$ was arbitrary it follows that $\|x\zeta\|\leq1$, and since $\zeta\in\text{ball}\ \mathcal{H}$ was arbitrary, it follows that $\|x\|\leq 1$, that is, $x\in B$.